# page_processor for homepage mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have this in default mezza urls

```
url("^$", "mezzanine.pages.views.page", {"slug": "/"}, name="home"),
```

I have this in my app models

```
class HomePage(Page):
    '''
    A page representing the format of the home page layout
    '''
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subheading = models.CharField(max_length=500,
        help_text="The subheading just below the heading")
    action_link = models.URLField()

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _("Home page")
    verbose_name_plural = _("Home pages")
```

Homepage loads up fine, via admin and on slug, /

I want to add out a mere text, say, "Just Testing" to HomePage context, and have done this:

```
@processor_for(HomePage)
def show_my_string(request, page):
    return {"item": "Just testing"}
```

The {{ item }} isn't showing up when I access it on homepage page.

I've done the above for Contact using example on mezzanine docs, but the Homepage isn't working.

Anything special to get it working for the homepage? What am I missing?

Comment: Just to check the obvious - what file is your `@processor_for` method sitting in?

Comment: Figured it out the hard way. Cache was the culprit.